# How to fix the Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' using react

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

```
const _defaults: UserCredential = {
  user: null,
  token: null,
  server: 'US',
  remember: false,
};


function setAxiosDefaults(server: string, token: string) {
  const SERVER_DATA = serverConfig[server || 'AUS'];

  if (SERVER_DATA) {
    Axios.defaults.baseURL = SERVER_DATA.api;
  }

  Axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = token;
}

export function AppCredentials({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, getSavedCredentials());
  const SERVER = serverConfig[state.server || 'AUS'];

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.interceptors.response.use(( response: AxiosResponse ) => response, ({ response }) => {
      return Promise.reject(response);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.server)
    setAxiosDefaults(state.server, state.token);
  }, [state.user, state.server, state.token]);

return (......)
}
```

the error is `Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

because the value is string which is US, but I'm getting this error. How do I fix on it?

Comment: On which line this error show up?

Comment: share minimum reproducible example, not maximum :)